# xml size Ui design android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a question for you, how to determine the size of the views so that the sizes do not confuse in different mobile phones and do not have any design problems.

I am doing xml coding as follows, which is different in different sizes of phones!

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    app:contentPadding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="******"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do. Use constraint layout inside card view and add parent for card view as Constraint layout as well. Secondly use sdp library for android. It will change size of widgets according to the screen size.